# Is it possible to paste Excel / CSV data from clipboard to DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, datagridview, csv

I use DataGridView control to manage a simple dictionary (several columns and a few hundred rows). DataGridView functionality is almost sufficient. I can add new rows, modify values and copy data from it to Excel. One thing I cannot do is to copy data from Excel to my control. Is it possible with some properties? Or is some code required to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can!

Take a look at some of the code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/DataGridViewCopyPaste.aspx) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 5):

**this has been edited from the codeprojet writeup. Slightly different** `

```
private void PasteClipboard()
        {
            try
            {
                string s = Clipboard.GetText();
                string[] lines = s.Split('\n');
                int iFail = 0, iRow = dgData.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                int iCol = dgData.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                DataGridViewCell oCell;
                if (dgData.Rows.Count < lines.Length)
                    dgData.Rows.Add(lines.Length-1);
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    if (iRow < dgData.RowCount && line.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string[] sCells = line.Split('\t');
                        for (int i = 0; i < sCells.GetLength(0); ++i)
                        {
                            if (iCol + i < this.dgData.ColumnCount)
                            {
                                oCell = dgData[iCol + i, iRow];
                                if (!oCell.ReadOnly)
                                {
                                    if (oCell.Value==null|| oCell.Value.ToString() != sCells[i])
                                    {
                                        oCell.Value = Convert.ChangeType(sCells[i],
                                                              oCell.ValueType);
                                      //  oCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
                                    }
                                    else
                                        iFail++;
                                    //only traps a fail if the data has changed 
                                    //and you are pasting into a read only cell
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            { break; }
                        }
                        iRow++;
                    }
                    else
                    { break; }
                    if (iFail > 0)
                        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} updates failed due" +
                                        " to read only column setting", iFail));
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The data you pasted is in the wrong format for the cell");
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the excel sheet to a dataset then bind the dataset to the grid. I think you should be able to make your amendments then write out to excel again when finished editing.

Answer (score 0):

Also this MSDN link: [how to PASTE (Ctrl+V, Shift+Ins) the data from clipboard to DataGridView](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e9cee429-5f36-4073-85b4-d16c1708ee1e/how-to-paste-ctrlv-shiftins-the-data-from-clipboard-to-datagridview-datagridview1-c?forum=winforms)

With code for .NET C#, VB and C++

(In the GetData method you probably want to specify Format.UnicodeText)